# Code won't output last 1/3 of output needed

Tags: python-3.x

```
Enter food item name:
hot dog
Enter item price:
2.00
Enter item quantity:
5

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $2.00 = $10.00
Total cost: $10.00


Enter second food item name:
ice cream
Enter item price:
2.50
Enter item quantity:
4

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $2.00 = $10.00
4 ice cream @ $2.50 = $10.00
Total cost: $20.00

15% gratuity: $3.00
Total with tip: $23.00
```

(^EXPECTED OUTPUT, my code does not sum the total cost of both items along with not outputting the gratuity and total with tip).

```
# FIXME (1): Finish reading item price and quantity, then output a receipt
item_name = input('Enter food item name:\n')
item_price = float(input('Enter item price:\n'))
item_quantity = int(input('Enter item quantity:\n\n'))

print('RECEIPT')
total_cost1 = f'{item_quantity * item_price:.2f}'
receipt = print(item_quantity, item_name, '@', f'${item_price:.2f} = ${total_cost1}')
print(f'Total cost: ${total_cost1}\n\n')

#FIXME (2): Read in a second food item name, price, and quantity, then output a second receipt
item_name2 = input('Enter second food item name:\n')
item_price2 = float(input('Enter item price:\n'))
item_quantity2 = int(input('Enter item quantity:\n\n'))

print('RECEIPT')
total_cost2 = f'{item_quantity2 * item_price2:.2f}'

print(item_quantity, item_name, '@', f'${item_price:.2f} = ${total_cost1}')
print(item_quantity2, item_name2, '@', f'${item_price2:.2f} = ${total_cost2}')
total_cost = str(total_cost1) + str(total_cost2)
print(f'Total Cost: ${total_cost}\n')

#FIXME (3): Add a gratuity and total with tip to the second receipt
gratuity = str(total_cost) * float(0.15)
total_plus_tip = str(total_cost) + str(gratuity)
print(f'15% gratuity: ${gratuity}')
print(f'Total with tip: ${total_plus_tip}')
```

Comment: do you know the difference between a string and an integer/float?

Comment: @Yarin_007 yes a string is the string of characters that are not a "value" and the inter/float is an actual number correlated to a value. Im confused on the error i am getting in the FIXME 3 portion and i added the str() and float() to possibly fix the issue like it has in the past but ive hit a substantial roadblock

Comment: `total_cost1 = f'{item_quantity * item_price:.2f}'` You're calculating total_cost1 as a string instead of a number.  This causes a problem later on when you want to add total_cost1 and total_cost2, because adding two things together with the plus sign works very differently for numbers than it does for strings.

Comment: For numbers, `5 + 6 = 11`.  But for strings, `"5" + "6" = "56"`.  Do you see the difference?